# How to close the form in ASP.NET with a LinkButton?

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:LinkButton ID2="lnbClose" SkinID="LinkButton" runat="server"
  meta:resourcekey="lnbClose" onclick="javascript: window.close()
```

How to close the form in ASP.Net with a LinkButton?

I am in Web Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
   private void lnkButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
   {
    Session.Abandon();
    string script = "<script language=javascript>window.close();</script>";
    RegisterStartupScript("showMessage", script);
  }
```

Comment: for registrestartupscript what refrence is requeired?

Comment: what refrence?pleaze write here